# Android Rotation Vector and Rotation Matrix

Tags: android, opengl-es, linear-algebra, android-sensors, rotational-matrices

So I previously asked a question more about what ind of sensor to use for the application I'm building. After some research I know now that it's the rotation vector that I want to use for I want to be able to move a virtual cube on my tablet according to the orientation of the device.

Let's imagine the tablet is in a given orientation O1 and therefore the orientation vector gives me a rotation matrix OM1
Let's imagine now that I lock the screen and move the tablet and rotate it so that it is afterwards, just before unlocking the screen in a given Orientation O2 and the orientation vector (which is stopped during the locked screen) will give when the screen is back on a rotation matrix OM2.

I want my virtual cube to remain in the position it was before the screen was locked when I unlock it again.

Of course for that I have already set up a rotation matrix in my code that keeps in memory the rotation matrix when the system pauses (i.e when I lock the screen).
So that when the screen is back the cube is in the right position.

However, when I move my tablet again (rotation) I want the cube to respond to these rotations according to the orientation matrix OM1 it had before the screen was locked and not just based on the orientation matrix that is given at any moment by the rotation vector sensor.

I am guessing that I need to compute somehow a differenceMatrix that will give me how to go from OM1 to OM2. But even with that I don't get what I want yet.

Here are the few operations i've tried:

```
if(hasLocked == true){
      Matrix.transposeM(transposed,0,mRotationLock,0); //mRotationLock is the rotation matrix that I save when the screen goes off
      Matrix.multiplyMM(mDifferenceRotation, 0, transposed, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);
      System.arraycopy(mDifferenceRotation,0,mRotationMatrix,0,16);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean actually locking the screen? Like what happens when you turn a device screen off and on?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. My problem is not turning it on or off. Basically my problem lies within the rotation matrix. I'm guessing there are some computation I could do to get the results I'm looking for but I'm still looking for the answer ^^'

Comment: Suppose at O1 the device lies flat with the device y-axis points north and the device is locked. At O2 the device is rotated so that the x-axis points north. Now suppose the device is lifted up 90 degrees. Do you want to show the cube flip on the side or up? It seems from your question that you want the cube flip on the side. If this is so, it is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing another matrix you must store and transposing the wrong matrix.

In addition to the `mRotationLock` (`OM1`), when the screen come unlocked you should store the opposite of the current `OM2` matrix called `OM20T` below. You can do this with a transpose. If you had more code I'd show that bit. Then the calculation is:

```
rotationMatrix = OM1 * OM20T * OM2
```

In other words we are rotating with `OM2` to apply the current vector, then `OM20T` to undo the first direction vector we were facing in **after** screen on. Then `OM1` to apply the rotate as it was **before** screen off. `OM1 * OM20T` can be calculated once on screen on.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks a lot ! I will check it out tomorrow to see if it works ! In case something's I will let you know ! But the way you say it sounds logical :-). Thanks again.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks a lot for this very helpful answer. It all sounds so easy in the end. I don't know how I could not see that ^^. Anyway thanks a lot. I would upvote this answer if I had enough rep ^^'

Comment: Glad it worked for you, tell me did you use transpose to find `OM20T`? I wasn't sure if my idea about negating the vector would work.

Comment: That's what I did indeed. First I get the transpose when the screen gets back on (and only once). Then I use the multiplication just like you gave it and it works perfectly :).

Comment: Apparently still have an error. Dunno where it comes from. It works in most cases but doesn't work in some. Should I edit the question to add my current code?

Comment: Best to go with another question. Try to diagnose it as best you can yourself first.

Comment: Ok thanks ! That's what I am going to do then. I will try and fix it by myself for some time and if I can't get near the answer again will create a new post. Do I have anyway to contact you in case I'm stuck again?

Comment: Post link to new question here and I'll be sure to take a look for you.

Comment: Everything works. Was just a small bug in my code. Thanks again :)